# Display of Controls in MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

1. Initially I am loading a MVC view(vbhtml) in a Grid Format(as Table) by fetching data from Database. Grid format rows contain one dropdown and two  textbox and two buttons for adding and deleting of the row
2. Once when I click on add button, a new row been added beneath the current row index. I used to construct all the table values as a json string and pass it to controller using ajax.
3. From there I am trying to reload the view using `RedirectToAction("actionname", object)`

Problems:

1. Newly added field/row are not visible in to the view, but it is available to the object
2. `RedirectToAction("actionname", object)` is not being called.

Comment: Please provide some code and maybe splitting up your question as it looks like only one issue.

Comment: Hi Frlan,here is my Code1. Thisis the startup Action
Function Action1() As ActionResult  dim obj as new Class1() 
  If Not Session("Constructvalue") Is Nothing Then
            obj= CType(Session("Constructvalue"), Perustiedot)
            Session("Constructvalue") = Nothing
        Elseobj=Fetch value from database
        End If Return View(obj) End Function

Comment: 2. @For Each objdetail As Class1Detail In Model.obj 
      @<tr> <td>@Html.TextBox("objdetail.M",objdetail.M) </td>
 <td>@Html.TextBox("objdetail.P", oobjdetail.P) </td>
<td> <input id="frmPlus" type="button" class="btnAdd BUTTON"  value="+" /></td><td align="left"> <input id="frmMinus" type="button" class="btnDelete BUTTON"  value="-" /></td></tr>Next
3.While clicking on + i used to construct the whole Table string and convert it to jason using ajax and call action in controller

Comment: 4. Public Function Fetchresult(JAvalue As Class1) As ActionResult
        Session("Constructvalue") = JAvalue
        Return RedirecttoAction("Action1")
 End Function

Comment: Please edit your question and add it to it. Keep care of proper format. Makes people easier to read and/or understand your issue.

Comment: You need to edit you question with new code - its unreadable in the comments. And ajax calls stay on the same page (that's the reason for using it) so having `RedirectToAction()` in the controller wont do anything. Just return a value indicating success, then dynamically add a new row to the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in web.config file in asp.net

if page has querystring than it should be rewrite like this

```
 <rewrite url="~/WhyUsDetail/(.+)" to="~/Educational_Connect_Why_Us_Detail_Page.aspx?WhyUsDetail=$1"/>
```

else

```
<rewrite url="~/eNewsletter" to="~/Educational_Connect_E_News_Letter.aspx"/>
```